# Pandas Dataframe: Is there a way to fill the missing values in cycles within groups?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fill the missing values of numbers in my data frame. Each variable group has dates ranging from 1 to 100 and once a date reaches 100, some variables have a 2nd cycle of dates starting again from 1. Within a variable, `date` can be repetitive. I need to fill them from numbers 1 to 100. For instance, A has values 1,2,3,3,4,5,6,10 and again 1,2,3,3,4. I need them to be 1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14.........100 and again 1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14.........100. When I'm filling the date, I would like to fill `NaN` in the rest of the columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,10,1,2,3,3,4,1,1,1,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4],
               "var": ["A","A","A", "A", "A", "A","A","A","A", "A", "A","A","A", "B", "B", "B","B","B","B" ,"C", "C", "C","C", "D","D","D","D","D","D"],
               "no": [ 1.5, 1.5,1, 2.2, 3.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 2, 3,1, 2.2, 3.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 2, 3,9,1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 2, 3,9],
               "value": [ -1.135632, 1.212112,0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632, 1.212112, -0.173215,
                         0.119209, -1.044236, -0.861849, None,0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632, 1.212112, -0.173215,
                         0.119209, -1.044236, -0.861849, None,0.87,1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 2, 3,9]})
```

```
 date  var  no      value
0   1   A   1.5    -1.135632
1   2   A   1.5     1.212112
2   3   A   1.0     0.469112
3   3   A   2.2    -0.282863
4   4   A   3.5    -1.509059
5   5   A   1.5    -1.135632
6   6   A   1.5     1.212112
7   10  A   1.2    -0.173215
8   1   A   1.3     0.119209
9   2   A   1.1    -1.044236
10  3   A   2.0    -0.861849
11  3   A   3.0    NaN
12  4   A   1.0    0.469112
13  1   B   2.2    -0.282863
14  1   B   3.5    -1.509059
15  1   B   1.5    -1.135632
16  4   B   1.5    1.212112
17  4   B   1.2    -0.173215
18  4   B   1.3    0.119209
19  1   C   1.1    -1.044236
20  1   C   2.0    -0.861849
21  1   C   3.0    NaN
22  2   C   9.0    0.870000
23  2   D   1.2    1.200000
24  3   D   1.3    1.300000
25  3   D   1.1    1.100000
26  3   D   2.0    2.000000
27  4   D   3.0    3.000000
28  4   D   9.0    9.000000
```

Desired output would be:

```
date   var  no      value
1       A   1.5    -1.135632
2       A   1.5     1.212112
3       A   1.0     0.469112
3       A   2.2    -0.282863
4       A   3.5    -1.509059
5       A   1.5    -1.135632
6       A   1.5     1.212112
7       A       NaN        NaN
8       A       NaN        NaN 
9       A       NaN        NaN  
.       .       ....       ..........
.       .       ....       ..........
.       .       ....       ..........
100 A   1.2    -0.173215
```

This is just an example of one group. I have atleast 300 such groups with a total of 100,000 rows in the dataframe. Here, the date 3 is repeated but I need that to stay as it is. Please help!

Comment: Pardon me but fill it with what?

Comment: I need to fill them from numbers 1 to 100. For instance, A has values 1,2,3,3,4,5,6,10 and again 1,2,3,3,4. I need them to be 1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14.........100 and again 1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14.........100. Please let me know if its still unclear

Comment: What about B, C and D? Also, why does A have two 3s in between? How do I know when it should be +1, and when there must be a duplicate in between?

Comment: I just gave an example output of one group because it would become too long. The data is very dirty and hence some dates (not just 3) are repetitive. Sorry :(

Comment: If I understand correctly, your dictionary's entries don't have the same length and you want the ones where something is lacking to have NAN as their value?

Comment: What should happen to those who start at one again?

Comment: @PaulRousseau Yes, they are not of the same length. I want to fill values only in the ```date``` column and the corresponding values of other columns can be set to ```NaN```

Comment: @PaulRousseau When ```date``` starts at 1 again, it means a new cycle has started

Comment: The problem is that you have the same dates in the same group. That makes it logically difficult to treat.

Comment: @PaulRousseau yes! I've looked at tens of answers to fill the column but couldn't find anything similar. Thanks anyway for taking a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A revised answer:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,10,1,2,3,3,4,1,1,1,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4],
               "var": ["A","A","A", "A", "A", "A","A","A","A", "A", "A","A","A", "B", "B", "B","B","B","B" ,"C", "C", "C","C", "D","D","D","D","D","D"],
               "no": [ 1.5, 1.5,1, 2.2, 3.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 2, 3,1, 2.2, 3.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 2, 3,9,1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 2, 3,9],
               "value": [ -1.135632, 1.212112,0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632, 1.212112, -0.173215,
                         0.119209, -1.044236, -0.861849, None,0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632, 1.212112, -0.173215,
                         0.119209, -1.044236, -0.861849, None,0.87,1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 2, 3,9]})

group_ident=[]
for df_group_index in df['var']:
    if df_group_index in group_ident:
        pass
    else:
        group_ident.append(df_group_index)

counter=[0 for i in range(len(group_ident))]

df_default=pd.DataFrame({"date":[i for i in range(len(df))],
"var":["A" for i in range(len(df))],
"no":[nan for i in range(len(df))],
"value":[nan for i in range(len(df))]})
for index in range(len(df_default)):
    date_case=0
    if df['date'][index]<counter[group_ident.index(df['var'][index])]:
        date_case=counter[group_ident.index(df['var'][index])]+df['date'][index]
    else:
        date_case=df['date'][index]
        counter[group_ident.index(df['var'][index])]=df['date'][index]
    print('date case = ' +str(date_case))
    print(counter[group_ident.index(df['var'][index])])
    for key in df:
        if key == 'date':
            df_default[key][index]=date_case
        else:
            df_default[key][index]=df[key][index]




print(df_default)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just want a column to organize the dates, regardless of what the actual date column says. Here's a solution that creates a new column called "Date_New" that does this for you. Here, Date_New lists 1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14.........100 for the groups and subgroups.

Also, the example you provided already has the NaN values displaying as NaNs. If your actual data is different, you can replace any string with NaN using the first line in my answer. [i.e. df.replace("Nothing", np.NaN) or df.replace("Nada", np.NaN)]

```py
#Replace whatever strings here with NaNs
df = df.replace("None", np.NaN)

#Create separate dataframes for each group
df_groups = df.groupby('var')

date_list = []
counter = 0

#Loop through every group, assigning the index number to date_list
#If index > 100, start the count over by subtracting 99 
for group, df_group in df_groups:
    for i, row in zip(range(len(df_group)), df_group.iterrows()):
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter <= 100:
            date_list.append(i+1)
        else:
            date_list.append(i-99)

#Create a new column called Date_new       
df['Date_New'] = date_list
```